# React Fetch: Getting json result but showing network error

Tags: json, reactjs, ssl, localhost, fetch

I spent the day setting up ssl on my local machine. I am running a wamp stack to build an api locally for testing. This endpoint is set up for ssl now and works perfect. I have a simple route setup that returns a json response.

`https://localhost/api/test`

It works via firefox by visiting that address.

Now, I am running a react app on

`localhost:3000`

The problem I am having is that I am trying out the `fetch()` api and using an example found on the react site (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html). Here is the code but it's extremely simple.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Api extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://localhost/api/test")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>
              {item.name} {item.price}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Api;
```

The kicker is, if I look at the console, I am getting a **200** response code from the request and also the actual **JSON** response with the proper data....yet for some reason in the app it is printing **NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**

I would understand the error if it wasn't getting the proper response or code but this just doesn't make sense.

Any advice would be helpful and appreciated!

Comment: @YUzhva Yes, then I get an html response, which converts to a JSON.parse error. It actually makes the request to my react server/port `http://localhost:3000/api/test` which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @YUzhva I am getting the correct content type in both situations as well as a json payload in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it was a CORS issue...which I didn't think would be a problem since everything is local. I had to add the following to my Flight Api backend.

```
Flight::before('json', function () {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that CORS is enabled in your HTTP headers which you can do from server side and for client side you have to just write mode:'cors' in your fetch api call, because the server would throw an error and your browser would not be able to load the content served for the requested client.